# How to specify example value for a parameter in C# XML doc comments?

Tags: c#, xml, swagger, comments

If you are using C# XML doc comments and you have a `param` to provide a description of a function parameter, how can you provide an example value (e.g. `"San Francisco"` or `5`)?

Here is an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Lookup EAN barcode value, return product data
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Lookup an input EAN barcode and return key details about the product</remarks>
/// <param name="value">Barcode value</param>
/// <returns>JSON describing matching product data to the entered barcode</returns>
[HttpPost, Route("ean")]
public BarcodeLookupResponse EanLookup([FromBody]string value)
```

Here, for the parameter named "value", I would like to provide an example EAN barcode, e.g. "QN1318481" to document an example value (not an example code snippet)

Comment: @RufusL Is it okay to use `<example>` in middle of `<param>`?

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for the feedback.  I added an example and clarification above.  Really I am trying to provide an example value for the parameter, not an example code snippet

Comment: Is this for intellisense in the editor? Sorry, I'm still not clear what output you're trying to get, and where. What about: `/// <param name="value">Barcode value (i.e. "QN1318481")</param>`? Also, you might consider naming the parameter `barcode` instead of `value`, just to make it more clear.

Comment: @RufusL I want to provide example values since this is an API and we are using Swagger to generate OpenAPI documentation and OpenAPI documentation supports "example values".  Since our OpenAPI is generated from doc comments wanted to see if there is a way.  Are you saying there is just no way to do that?

Comment: No, I provided an example in my last comment. But this is the first time you mentioned anything about OpenAPI and its "example values" support (which I know nothing about). You should probably update your question with these important details, and add the OpenAPI tag to your question.

Comment: @RufusL But your example doesn't provide a way to have an example value syntactically - it is just saying put it as free text.  Ideally this value should be expressed through syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this to generate a OpenAPI documentation using Swagger, it's perfectly fine to use `example` value inside `param` tag. According to [Include Descriptions from XML Comments](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments) (point 3) you can write something like

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Lookup EAN barcode value, return product data
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Lookup an input EAN barcode and return key details about the product</remarks>
/// <param name="value" example="QN1318481">Barcode value</param>
/// <returns>JSON describing matching product data to the entered barcode</returns>
[HttpPost, Route("ean")]
public BarcodeLookupResponse EanLookup([FromBody]string value)
```

Swagger UI will automatically use this value, just tried the same few days ago and it works fine

Comment: Actually - what about for a property on a class?  For example, if the parameter is of type MyObject and MyObject has two properties MyProperty1 and MyProperty2 - how to provide example values for MyProperty1 and MyProperty2?

Comment: @Abr just put a separate `<example>my value</example>` tag. Point 4 in link above in the answer shows that:)

Comment: Thanks!  One more question, sorry - does this work in Swashbuckle for .NET Framework?

Comment: @Abr don't about .NET FW, tried only with .NET Core

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski is there a way to change the placeholder without actually adding an example value?